# Angular: Animations for an immutable model inside ngFor

Tags: css, angular

I've been unable to get CSS transitions working when using an array of immutable model objects.

Does angular require an in-place update to the property for these to work, or am I doing something wrong?

As an example: (https://plnkr.co/edit/PBSPtk9vMig7cxnHoJqA)

```
export class Box {
  constructor(public selected:boolean){
  }
}

function toggle(box:Box):Box{
  return new Box(!box.selected)
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <ul>
  <li *ngFor="let box of boxes">
   <div 
    style="display:inline-block; width: 20px; height:20px; transition: 1s; margin:5px; cursor:pointer;"
    [ngStyle]="{'background': box.selected?'green':'red'}"
    > </div>
    <button (click)="toggle_in_place(box)">toggle (in-place)</button>
    <button (click)="toggle_replace_box(box)">toggle (replace box)</button>
    <button (click)="toggle_replace_array(box)">toggle (replace array)</button>
   </li>
   </ul>
  `,
})
export class App {

  boxes: Box[];

  constructor() {
    this.boxes = [new Box(true), new Box(false), new Box(true)];
    }

  toggle_in_place(box:Box){
    box.selected=!box.selected;
  }

  toggle_replace_box(box:Box){
     const index = this.boxes.indexOf(box);
     this.boxes[index]=toggle(box);
  }

  toggle_replace_array(box:Box){
    this.boxes = this.boxes.map(v=>v===box?toggle(v):v);
  }
}
```

Here I'm trying to animate the color of the div through

```
[ngStyle]="{'background': box.selected?'green':'red'}"
```

box.selected can be updated by:

- changing the property in-place (toggle_in_place),
- replacing the 'box' model (toggle_replace_box)
- replacing the entire array (toggle_replace_array).

but toggle_in_place is the only one that results in a visible transition.

Is this just something I have to live with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening here: When the array changes the ngFor compares the object references in the new array to the old and re-renders any elements that have changed, which breaks the css transitions.

To solve this, ngFor can be given a tracking function which will then be used instead of the reference comparison.

To fix, specify a tracking function to use an id rather than object reference:

```
trackingFunction(index:number, box:Box){
  return box.id;
}
```

Have ngFor use it:

```
 <li *ngFor="let box of boxes;trackBy:trackingFunction">
```

Example:
https://plnkr.co/edit/4OXemdSf1Hsm1NU6ZhzT

Answer (score 0):

I think it is something you have to live with. In the latter two cases, since you're creating a new instance of the box each time, it has nothing to transition from.

You could probably make a component which is basically a wrapper around a box and can pass a "transition" boolean to its constructor. Workarounds are pretty dependent on the use case though.

Comment: The transition shouldn't care about the box instance, it'll only see the resulting DOM changes, right?

I assume what's happening is that the box instance change, for some reason forces angular to replace the entire div, rather than just updating the style. 

Maybe because it's in inside the ngFor?

Comment: You have that right. Angular is rebuilding the DOM with the new instances instead of updating the existing one since a new box is being returned.